# how to get a quote value in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

Hi i am getting a attribute value using check box dynamically in java server pages.If check box is checked then it give value no-follow else null.
but i want if my value is null then rel also not show in anchor tag. how can i achieve this

my code is

```
<% String relAttribute = properties.get("./relAttribute","false");
String relAttributeValue=relAttribute.equals("true")?"nofollow":"";%>
<a class="play" title="Play video" target="_top" href="<%=appURL%>" rel="<%=relAttributeValue%>" >
```

Comment: If `relAttribute` is null, then NullPointerException throws right ?

Comment: no still not getting any exception but it is showing only attribute. another thing i can do generate the value of rel only the basis of check also but i don't want to do it. and i also can do like on chek String relAttributeValue=relAttribute.equals("true")?"rel="nofollow"":"";%> then double quotes come

Answer (score 0):

you can check your attribute with JSTL and place the content in the body of the `c:if` tag

```
<c:if test="${relAttribute is not empty)">
```